# Continuous Integration, Git branches and NuGet

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, nuget, branch

I have project which I claimed as Open Source and which I host on GitHub. What I would like to do is, automatically build the project after each commit and publish the build as Nightly-NuGet package. From time I want to publish a build as stable to the main NuGet package

What my workflow looks like at the moment:

- Commit is pushed to GitHub/*master
- Github calls build server by Webhook
- Build server builds solution, builds Nightly-NuGet package
- Build server uploads Nightly-NuGet package

When I want to publish a "stable" I have to login to my build server and start the following:

- Build server builds main NuGet-Package from last build
- Build server uploads main NuGet-Package

---

But I have the feeling that this is "bad style". So I thought of the following workflow.

- Add a new "nightly" branch in my GitHub repo
- Each commit is pushed to GitHub/*nightly
- Github calls build server by Webhook
- Build server builds solution from /*nightly, builds Nightly-NuGet package
- Build server uploads Nightly-NuGet package

When I want to publish a "stable" I pull /*nightly to /*master.

- After the merge with /*master, GitHub calls my build server via Webhook
- Build server builds main NuGet-Package from l/*master
- Build server uploads main NuGet-Package

---

Is the second solution better style? How do you solve this kind of scenario? How does best practice look?

Comment: Your current workflow seems fine to me. As an improvement, you could push a tag every time you want to publish a stable version, and use the webhooks to automate the publishing.

Comment: Can I trigger a GitHub Webhook when a tag is commited? Or in other words - are there different hooks fur usual commits and commits which contain a label?

Comment: I haven't used GitHub - in GitLab, you can define different hooks for different events, I'm assuming GitHub would have something similar.